# Como ativar o rolamento pelo scroll do mouse de uma modal em Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-3, rolamento, modal

Como faço para que a barra de rolagem de um arquivo PDF, carregado dentro de um `iframe` (que está dentro de uma `modal` do `Bootstrap`),  funcione  quando a barra for clicada **e** quando rodar o `scroll` do mouse (só funciona quando a barra é clicada).

Comment: Mesmo dando foco no scroll não funciona?

Comment: Fiz uma edição pra tentar deixar mais claro o que você precisa, pelo que entendi. Ainda está na fila de análise, mas depois se for aprovada você pode alterar ou retornar facilmente pra versão anterior. Dá uma olhada.

Comment: Editei de novo, olhando melhor pelo título acho que era justamente o contrário. Confere aí... E coloca aí o código, senão fica difícil alguém responder. btw, já conferiu se não é pela configuração do seu mouse?

Comment: @gustavox não tem nada a ver com a configuração do mouse, acredito que seja a configuração da própria modal.

Comment: Você devia postar o código, pra aumentar as chances de alguém responder. E neste caso o ideal talvez fosse criar um exemplo verificável mesmo (usando o snippet do site, e/ou jsfiddle).

Answer (score -1):

Se você está usando algum plugin como o Perfect Scrollbar ou outro, o seu componente modal não está adquirindo o efeito do plugin que se sobrepõe à barra normal de rolagem.

Precisa então aplicar através do JS o efeito ao componente:

```
$('#nomeModal').perfectScrollbar();
```

Espero que ajude, eu tive esse mesmo problema.